# Aborted connection 10 to db: 'acore_auth' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

My AzerothCore `docker-compose` fails with the following:

```
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645200Z 10 [Note] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'acore_auth' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645268Z 8 [Note] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'acore_characters' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645271Z 9 [Note] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'acore_auth' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645487Z 4 [Note] Aborted connection 4 to db: 'acore_world' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645273Z 7 [Note] Aborted connection 7 to db: 'acore_characters' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645549Z 5 [Note] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'acore_world' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2019-05-28T16:53:22.645302Z 6 [Note] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'acore_characters' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real error was right before the database logs:

```
ac-worldserver_1  | Map file '/azeroth-server/data/maps/0004331.map': does not exist!
```

which means: the datafiles are missing.

As the [official guide](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker) said, I had to:

> Put your data files into the docker/worldserver/data/ folder that is inside azerothcore-wotlk.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems after docker-compose-up creating database which world kept shutting down and having this on log

```
ac-database_1     | Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975275Z 10 [Note] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'acore_auth' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975247Z 7 [Note] Aborted connection 7 to db: 'acore_characters' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975278Z 8 [Note] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'acore_characters' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975789Z 3 [Note] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'acore_world' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975889Z 9 [Note] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'acore_auth' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
ac-database_1     | 2020-04-10T10:23:13.975272Z 5 [Note] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'acore_world' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1 exited with code 137
```

Which fixed by increasing memory from default 1 gb to 2 gb.
Here is how to increase 
https://www.petefreitag.com/item/848.cfm